# The zero value of a slice is not nil

Tags: go, slice

I was following the example https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/10
I modified the code expecting to get the same result. I did not. Is this a bug, or a documentation error? The tour states

> A nil slice has a length and capacity of 0.

My y variable has a length and capacity of 0.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func myPrint(z []int) {
    fmt.Println(z, len(z), cap(z))
    if z == nil {
        fmt.Println("nil!")
    }
}

func main() {
    var z  []int 
    y := []int {}
    myPrint(z)
    myPrint(y)
}
```

Here is my output.

```
[] 0 0
nil!
[] 0 0
```

I was expecting a second "nil"~ Why didn't I get it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The doc you referenced states that *a nil slice has a length and capacity of 0,* but not that *every* slice of length and capacity of zero is a nil slice. [The specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) only says that the value of an *uninitialized* slice is nil.

This is a convenience to support `len` and `cap` on slices which are uninitialised (nil). Otherwise we would need to check for non-nil first in order to avoid panic. (This also holds for other in-built types like maps or channels.)

In terms of the `fmt.Print` output, the difference in behaviour is similar to printing an uninitialised (nil) pointer vs pointer to an empty structure:

```
var s *struct{} // uninitialised pointer
fmt.Println(s)  // <nil>

s = &struct{}{} // pointer to an empty structure
fmt.Println(s)  // &{}
```

Comment: i do not think this is a right answer, a nil slice is not a pointer, i like @tgogos answer, which nil means the array under the slice is not init

Comment: @petelin you're right, a slice is not a pointer. I've removed the statement suggesting it is.

Answer (score 34):

### `nil` Vs `empty` slice

If we think of a slice like this:

```
[pointer] [length] [capacity]
```

then:

```
nil slice:   [nil][0][0]
empty slice: [addr][0][0] // it points to an address
```

> From: "Go in action" book:
>
> #### nil slice
>
> They’re useful when you want to represent a slice that doesn’t exist, such as when an exception occurs in a function that returns a slice.
>
> ```
> // Create a nil slice of integers.
> var slice []int
> ```
>
> #### empty slice
>
> Empty slices are useful when you want to represent an empty collection, such as when a database query returns zero results.
>
> ```
> // Use make to create an empty slice of integers.
> slice := make([]int, 0)
>
> // Use a slice literal to create an empty slice of integers.
> slice := []int{}
> ```
>
> Regardless of whether you’re using a nil slice or an empty slice, the built-in functions `append`, `len`, and `cap` work the same.

---

[Go playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/5bjyfO5OmB):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    var nil_slice []int
    var empty_slice = []int{}

    fmt.Println(nil_slice == nil, len(nil_slice), cap(nil_slice))
    fmt.Println(empty_slice == nil, len(empty_slice), cap(empty_slice))

}
```

prints:

```
true 0 0
false 0 0
```

Comment: I like your answer as one way to *see* it, but I think it would be useful to confirm (or deny) that this is the the actual memory layout of a nil slice. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39993797 seems to say that it is.

Answer (score 9):

In this case:

```
var z []int
```

You have declared a variable `z` but you did not initialize it.

In this case:

```
y := []int {}
```

You declared it and initialized it, you set it to an empty slice. Writing the second expression the long way makes the difference between the two expressions more clear:

```
var y []int = []int {}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your `y` variable *isn't* the zero value for a slice. It's allocated via an empty slice literal.

```
// both of these allocate a slice
y := []int{}
z := []int{1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: Then the documentation on the tour is not entirely correct.

Answer (score 0):

> A nil slice has a length and capacity of 0 and has no underlying array.

var s []string => no underlying array 
var s = []string => create a underlying array but his length is 0.