# How to assert map contains key?

Tags: dictionary, go, testing

I have an map object in golang of the type:  `*map[string]interface{}`    , how can I assert it contain certain keys?  Here is what I have:

```
type respObj struct {
    ExternalIds *map[string]interface{} `json:"externalIds,omitempty"`
}
myObj := getRespObj()
out, _ := json.Marshal(myObj)
fmt.Println("Response: ", string(out))
// {"externalIds":{"payroll":"bigmoney","serial":"GA3MXX4VV7","vin":"1G1YY3388L5112656"}}
assert.NotNil(t, myObj.ExternalIds)
assert.Contains(t, &myObj.ExternalIds, "payroll")
assert.Contains(t, &myObj.ExternalIds, "serial")
assert.Contains(t, &myObj.ExternalIds, "vin")
```

Currently throwing error:

```
Error:          "%!s(**map[string]interface {}=0xc0079bf920)" could not be applied builtin len()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a **map** to [`assert.Contains()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert#Contains).

`myObj.ExternalIds` is a pointer to a map, so `&myObj.ExternalIds` will be a pointer to a pointer to a map.

Instead of taking its address, dereference the pointer:

```
assert.Contains(t, *myObj.ExternalIds, "payroll")
assert.Contains(t, *myObj.ExternalIds, "serial")
assert.Contains(t, *myObj.ExternalIds, "vin")
```

Note that [maps are pointers under the hood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520624/why-slice-values-can-sometimes-go-stale-but-never-map-values/55521138#55521138). Its rare that you need a pointer to a map, [passing maps have pointer semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264339/what-do-value-semantics-and-pointer-semantics-mean-in-go/51265000#51265000), and it's efficient (only a pointer is passed under the hood).

Comment: Excellent point, I didn't know that map are pointers under hood, I will simply the struct for sure.