# Confused about append() behavior on slices

Tags: go, append, slice

```
func main() {
    slice := make([]int, 10, 10)
    slice[0] = 0
    slice[1] = 1

    slice1 := slice
    slice1[0] = 10000
    fmt.Println(slice)

    slice1 = append(slice1, 100)
    slice1[0] = 20000

    fmt.Println(slice)
}
```

result:

> [10000 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
>
> [10000 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

In my understanding, `slice` is a pointer, `slice1` and `slice` point to the same array, and the first output also proves this. But why did `slice`'s value remain unchanged after the append operation changed `slice1`?

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7 ff and https://blog.golang.org/slices. Basically you modify slice1 which is no longer backed by the same array than slice after appending to it.

Comment: Just a tip... setting the capacity as well size is redundant if they are the same. `make([]int, 10, 10)` might as well be `make([]int, 10)`

Comment: With ref. to the answers below, try this program https://play.golang.org/p/WM12iW9A4z, which sets the length 5 and capacity 10, you'll hopefully realize what's happening.

Comment: Basically, an append operation will require allocation of a newer array for a slice when the existing allocation is filled up (length = capacity)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`append()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) didn't change `slice1`; it can't as everything in Go is passed by value, so it only receives a copy of it. Since initially you created the `slice` with capacity equal to its length (`make([]int, 10, 10)`), any append operation with more than 0 elements requires allocation of a new, bigger array. This is what your `append()` call does. And it copies over the contents of the old array, and returns a slice value (slice header) pointing to the new array. And you *assign* the return value to `slice1`, and this [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) is what changes `slice1`.

Any assignment to `slice1` does not change the value of `slice`, they are 2 distinct variables, 2 distinct slice headers. So the appended elements will not be visible in `slice`. And since the `append()` had to create a new array, changes made to the *elements* of `slice1` and `slice` will also not be reflected in one another anymore.

To see what's inside a slice header, see [Are golang slices pass by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993688/are-golang-slices-pass-by-value/39993797#39993797)

To learn more about slices, read blog post [Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals).

Answer (score 2):

Because an append can decide to return an *entirely new copy* of the underlying array.