# golang proxy io.Writer behaves differently when used in a log.Logger

Tags: go

I am trying to implement a proxy that satisfies io.Writer, so I can plug it into a logger. The idea is that it will print the output like normal but also keeps a copy of the data to be read later.

The ProxyIO struct in the following code should do this, and indeed it does it as long as I directly call its Write() method. However, when I plug it into a log.Logger instance the output is unexpected.

(This is stripped down code, the original implementation I want to use is with a map and a circular pointer instead of the `[][]byte` buf used in the example code. Also I removed all the locking.)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

type ProxyIO struct {
    out io.Writer // the io we are proxying
    buf [][]byte
}

func newProxyIO(out io.Writer) *ProxyIO {
    return &ProxyIO{
        out: out,
        buf: [][]byte{},
    }
}

func (r *ProxyIO) Write(s []byte) (int, error) {
    r.out.Write(s)
    r.buf = append(r.buf, s)
    return len(s), nil
}

func main() {
    p := newProxyIO(ioutil.Discard)
    p.Write([]byte("test1\n"))
    p.Write([]byte("test2\n"))
    p.Write([]byte("test3\n"))
    l := log.New(p, "", 0)
    l.Print("test4")
    l.Print("test5")
    l.Print("test6")
    for i, e := range p.buf {
        fmt.Printf("%d: %s", i, e)
    }
}
```

(Here is the code on the playground https://play.golang.org/p/UoOq4Nd-rmI)

I would expect the following output from this code:

```
0: test1
1: test2
2: test3
3: test4
4: test5
5: test6
```

However, it will always print this:

```
0: test1
1: test2
2: test3
3: test6
4: test6
5: test6
```

The behaviour with my map implementation is the same. I also tried using a doubly linked list from `container/list` as storage, it's always the same. So I must be missing something substantial here.

Why am I seeing the last log output three times in the buffer instead of the last three lines of log output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source code for [`Logger.Print`](https://golang.org/src/log/log.go?s=8771:8799#L278) you'll see it calls [`logger.Output`](https://golang.org/src/log/log.go?s=5252:5306#L139). You'll notice how it sets the value of the string to `l.buf` and then calls `Write`

If you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39993797/24998) you'll see that even though everything is pass by value

> when you pass a slice to a function, a copy will be made from this
>   header, including the pointer, which will point to the same backing
>   array.

So when you do:

```
l.Print("test4")
l.Print("test5")
l.Print("test6")
```

Logger is effectively reusing the same slice and you're `append`ing a reference to that same slice three times so naturally upon printing it uses the most recent value set three times.

To fix this you can copy the `[]byte` before using it like this:

```
func (r *ProxyIO) Write(s []byte) (int, error) {
    c := make([]byte, len(s))
    copy(c, s)
    r.out.Write(c)
    r.buf = append(r.buf, c)
    return len(c), nil
}
```

Updated playground: https://play.golang.org/p/DIWC1Xa6w0R

Comment: I knew it was something substantial. slices are headers, slices are headers, slices are headers ...