# Append not working with a named type defined as slice of struct type

Tags: go, append, slice

Need a fresh look because something I do, I get wrong here.
I tried to append status to a slice, it wouldn't work

I tried using dereferencing as well

```
type ServerStatuses []ServerStatus
statuses := new(ServerStatuses)

status := &ServerStatus{
    time:      time,
    available: available,
    url:       url,
}

statuses = append(statuses, *status)
```

`append` will not work in such case in spite of statuses is a slice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's nothing to do with the named type. It's because `statuses` is a `*ServerStatuses`, which is a *pointer to a slice*, not a slice. You can only append to slices, not to pointers. Remember that `new` returns a pointer to the given type. If you replace `new(ServerStatuses)` with `ServerStatuses{}`, it works: https://play.golang.org/p/OYdTbLoVifD

Comment: Thanks, Adrian. Will the dereferencing help?

Comment: If I return a slice from function do I need to return a reference or slices are already passed by pointer?

Comment: Slices are passed by value like everything else in Go. Pointers are pointers, everything else is not. Whether you need to return a pointer from a function depends entirely on the context, that's not a question that has a universally-applicable answer.

Comment: @Adrian If i am not wrong, then `slices` are passed by reffernce unlike other types. See, https://play.golang.org/p/83BHVZgwLN3.

Comment: Nope - nothing in Go is passed by reference. Slices contain an internal pointer to an array which may be shared among multiple slices of the same array, but the slices themselves are still values.

Comment: Sorry for my wrong, and offcourse yes, you are right. `Slices` are passed by value. I have taken a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993688/are-golang-slices-passed-by-value.

Answer (score 4):

In Go, the `new` built-in function returns a pointer of specified type. So, `new(ServerStatuses)` gives you a pointer of `ServerStatuses`, type (`*ServerStatuses`).

And also you are using an append statement. But `append()` only appends to a `slice`. You are trying to append the pointed value of `status` var of type `SeverStatus` to the var `statuses` of type `*ServerStatuses`. That's why it's not going as you expect. If we simulate the statement you used against the corresponding types of the var:

```
statuses           =    append(  statuses,         *status       )
*ServerStatuses   <--   append(  *ServerStatuses,  ServerStatus  )
```

So, you have to declare `statuses` var as a `slice` type. For example,

```
statuses := make(ServerStatuses, 0)
```

See, an example https://play.golang.org/p/RXETzrxSVqm