# Do slices or arrays act as a global scope?

Tags: go, computer-science

I'm still new to programming. Forgive my lack of computer science knowledge. Not sure if this question is specific to Golang or computer science in general...

I always thought that functions do not alter variables/data held outside their own scope unless you use a return statement back into the other scope, or unless they are higher in the hierarchy of scopes. One may argue that functions `f1` and `f2` in this example are called from a lower scope. However, this still doesn't explain why I'm getting different results for variable `num` and `nums`.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func f1(a int) {
    a = 50 // this will not work, as it shouldn't
}

func f2(a ...int) {
    a[0] = 50 // this will work without return statement
    a[1] = 50 // this will work without return statement
}

func main() {

    num := 2
    nums := []int{2, 2}

    f1(num)
    f2(nums...)

    fmt.Printf("function f1 doesn't affect the variable num and stays: %v\n", num)
    fmt.Printf("function f2 affects the variable nums and results in: %v", nums)
```

**Questions:**

1. Why doesn't `f2` require a return statement to modify nums like num
   would within `f1`?
2. Golang functions are said to pass values (rather than reference),
   shouldn't that force the function to return copies?
3. Can this happen in other languages? (I think I may have
   seen this in other languages).

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct behaviour, since `a ...int` is equal to a slice e.g.: `a []int`

```
func f2(a []int) {
    a[0] = 50
    a[1] = 50
}
func main() {
    b := []int{2, 2}
    f2(b)
    fmt.Println(b) // [50 50]
}
```

And a slice is a view to the original data, here 'b'.

> "Why doesn't f2 require a return statement to modify nums like num would in f1?"

In `f2` you are using the slice, which has a pointer to the original array, so `f2` can change the outside array.

> "Golang functions are said to pass values (not reference), shouldn't that force to return copies? (If the question is related...)"

In `f2` the slice itself is passed by value, meaning pointer and length and capacity of the original array.

> "Can this happen in other languages? (I think I may have seen this in other langues)"

Too broad to answer, there are many languages and in general if you have a pointer to the outside world array, yes.

---

Edit:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func sum(a ...int) int {
    s := 0
    for _, v := range a {
        s += v
    }
    return s
}
func f2(a []int) {
    c := make([]int, len(a))
    copy(c, a)
    c[0] = 50
    fmt.Println(sum(c...)) // 52
}
func main() {
    b := []int{2, 2}
    fmt.Println(sum(1, 2, 3, 4)) // 10
    fmt.Println(sum(b...))       // 4

    f2(b)
    fmt.Println(b) // [2 2]
}
```

Notes:
The `sum()` function above is  a pure function, since it has no side effect.
The new `f2` function above is  a pure function, since it has no side effect: it makes a copy of `a` into `c` then calls the sum.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I understand that passing by reference simply means that it's making whatever surrounding code affect the local variable. However, I would think that a function without a return statement would not send back any transformation to affect that local code. The return statement could be used to dictate if the function overrides references or not. Not sure why it's designed that way. I don't know much about pointers, so I'm still digesting the other answer. However you put it in simple terms. Thank you.

Comment: To be precise this `f2` function is not a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), since it has a  side effect. and the philosophy of a slice is to use it this way and slice, I think is the most important data structure in Go, so you need to understand it this way, and this is by design. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just discovered that some functions cannot be pure. For some reason my brain thinks only in pure functional programming, so I didn't know that. One last question pls before I mark this as the answer... This may also help others. Are you saying the function is unpure due to the way I coded it, or because the pointer made it so?

Comment: in other words, is there a way to prevent this in the way I write the function (without touching the slice) ?

Comment: Yes, it is your choice, to make the function pure: You may copy the original slice, see the edit.

Comment: Even though I understand this is not technically a "Pure" function (within a compiler) and I could have copied the slice outside the function, I'm marking this as the answer since it answers how the function behaves rather than how slices behave and most of my 3 questions were about the return statement of the function or why the function behaves this way. It also gave me insight in the term "pure function" that I didn't know about, but yet naturally thought that way.

Answer (score 1):

In go, function arguments are passed by value. That means, if you pass an int (like in `f1`), compiler will pass the value of `f1`, essentially copying it. If the function takes a `*int` and you pass `&num`, then the compiler passes the value of `&num`, which is a pointer to `num`. When the function changes `*num`, the value of the variable outside the function will change. If the function changes `num`, the pointer value of `num` will change, and it will point to a different variable.

As a contrast, Java passes all primitive values as value, and all objects by reference. That is, if you pass an `int`, there is no way for the function to modify the value of that int that is visible to the caller. If you want to pass an int the function can modify, you put that in a class and pass an instance of that class in Java.

A slice (as in `f2`) contains a pointer to the underlying array. When you call a function with a slice, the slice header (containing a pointer to the underlying array) is copied, so when the function changes the slice elements, the underlying array elements change.

The question of scope is somewhat different. Scope of a function is all the variables it can see. Those are the global variables (if from different packages, exported global variables), function arguments, and if the function is declared nested within another function, all the variables visible in that function at that point.

Comment: I wasn't asking about the slicing reference, but about how the function works instead. And I think this might be the best answer as the second paragraph explains best (so far) why the function affects the slice even though it doesn't return anything. It has to do with how functions access memory. Does this also have anything to do with first-class citizen?

Comment: A function doesn't need to return something to affect places in memory otherwise invisible to it. If you pass a pointer to a function, then the function can assign values to that pointer to change wherever the pointer is pointing to. It may be pointing to variables the function otherwise doesn't have access.

Comment: ok.... I see, because in your first paragraph, you explained that functionality happens only if the function "takes" *int and "passes" &num. I thought this meant that the function parameter needs to have *int. But it appears that the pointer from the num variable passed into it is sufficient to cause this effect without changing the function's syntax. Is this correct?

Comment: No. Function f gets *int argument, the function calling f passed &num. You cannot pass a pointer to a function that isn't declared to get a pointer. That is: `func f(i *int)`, and you call `f` as: `f(&num)`, then `f` can change the value of `num`. In your original question: a slice contains a pointer, so the function can change the slice contents.

Answer (score 1):

1 & 2) Both questions can be answered when looking at how slices work in Go. There's [a blog article](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro) on it.

In general, all variables are passed by value in Go. You can use pointers (e.g. `*int` for `f1`) to pass by reference (or more correct, the address of the pointer).
However, slices are technically also passed by value.

When we look [here](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceHeader), we can get an idea how they work:

```
type SliceHeader struct {
    Data uintptr
    Len  int
    Cap  int
}
```

`Len` and `Cap` are integers, but `Data` is a pointer.

When this struct is copied (when passing by value), a copy of `Len`, `Cap` and `Data` will be made. Since `Data` is a pointer, any modifications made to the value it's pointing to will be visible after your function returns.

You can also [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39993797)

Comment: Thanks for answering. What I was trying to understand is why the function is returning a value in the absence of a return statement. You somewhat explain it with the struct example by making me understand that it's not the function the problem. However, I still don't understand why use pointers designed that way and how/why it would be used this way. Seems risky as it creates anti-patterns. What is the advantage?

Comment: @Alex, the function does not return anything.  Explaining the history of pointers (as pointers in Go are not special in any way) is a little too broad for a SO answer.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for replying. I know the function doesn't return anything and I understand how a slice is a reference. What I am asking is why the function doesn't block the reference to the slice since it doesn't have a return statement. What is it doing returning something? You even said it yourself, it shouldn't return anything. And I think it has something to do with how function accesses the memory. The function seems to act like everything else that's not a function.

Comment: @Alex, sorry, I don’t understand what you mean. You say you understand that the function does not return anything, then you go on to ask “What is it doing returning something?”. There are no returned values, period. I think you need to do some reading on what a pointer actually is, and why they are used. While it’s not aN acceptable question type here any longer, perhaps this old post can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome

Comment: Yeah, you are right that I don't know enough about pointers. It appears to me like pointers render a function completely unpure and throws "functional programming" completely outside the window. I'll look more into that. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex If the slice was a house, then the pointer to it is piece of paper with the address written on it. When passing this paper (or any copy of it) to somebody else, they will know where the house is located. If they change anything at the house that has the address that is written on *their* piece of paper, they will modify the house the original paper points to (as they are the same). To prevent this, one can `make` a new slice/house and [`copy`](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#copy) everything from the old one to it. Any modifications to *that* slice/house will *not* show up at the original one

Comment: @Alex: well of course functions with side effects are not pure, and do not fall into the category of pure functional programming. Go does not have constructs to enforce pure functions, so I don't understand the point of this comparison.

Comment: You've unintentionally given the answer even though you say you don't understand. The answer is: "Go does not have constructs to enforce pure functions". I think others beat you to it. But thank you for taking the time to answer.