# Copying struct value to a interface{ } in golang

Tags: go, pointers

I will like to understand why when I copy a struct value into an interface it behaves like it does. In this code can someone help me understand why when I copy the value from mySlice into foo3 it behaves different than the other copies?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

type SliceOfInt []int

// when passing a slice to a method you are passing this data. Lets prove it
type SliceHeader struct {
    Data uintptr
    Len  int
    Cap  int
}

// Print the header of a slice. Its Data. Len and Cap
func GetHeaderOfSliceOfInt(s unsafe.Pointer) *SliceHeader {
    // this header needs to point to &mySlice but compiler will not let us. we have to use unsafe pointers
    var header *SliceHeader
    pointerToMySlice := s
    header = ((*SliceHeader)(pointerToMySlice))
    return header
}

func main() {

    // On go everything is passed by coping values. When you pass a slice to a function you are passing this:
    // reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39993797/637142
    /*
        type SliceHeader struct {
            Data uintptr
            Len  int
            Cap  int
        }
    */

    // create a new slice
    var mySlice SliceOfInt = make([]int, 0)
    mySlice = append(mySlice, 123456789) // append this number to mySlice

    // now we have a slice with len:1 and capacity:1. Lets prove it

    header := GetHeaderOfSliceOfInt(unsafe.Pointer(&mySlice))
    fmt.Println(*header)
    // this prints: {824635465728 1 1}
    // this means that on memory address 824635465728 there is an array with cap:1 and len:1

    // copy that header to someOtherSlice
    someOtherSlice := mySlice
    header = GetHeaderOfSliceOfInt(unsafe.Pointer(&someOtherSlice))
    fmt.Println(*header)
    // prints the same value {824635465728 1 1}

    // anyways if I go to address 824635465728 on my computer I shoul dbe able to find integer 123456789
    pointerToInteger := unsafe.Pointer((*header).Data)
    var integerVal *int = ((*int)(pointerToInteger))
    fmt.Println(*integerVal)

    // if I copy like this, it will print the correct header {824635465728 1 1}
    foo1 := mySlice
    fmt.Println(*GetHeaderOfSliceOfInt(unsafe.Pointer(&foo1)))

    // copy like this will also print the correct header {824635465728 1 1}
    foo2 := foo1
    fmt.Println(*GetHeaderOfSliceOfInt(unsafe.Pointer(&foo2)))

    // If I copy like this it will print the incorrect header. Why?
    var foo3 interface{} = mySlice
    fmt.Println(*GetHeaderOfSliceOfInt(unsafe.Pointer(&foo3)))

    // this last line prints {4746976 824635330392 0}
}
```

The output of the program is:

```
{824635465728 1 1}
{824635465728 1 1}
123456789
{824635465728 1 1}
{824635465728 1 1}
{4746976 824635330392 0}
```

### Edit

I know that if I cast foo3 as: `foo3.(SliceOfInt)` it will work. But why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interface type, empty or not, is a type in its own right. It has its own memory representation and it is a legitimate member of Go's type system.

An interface value, and the value wrapped in that interface, are not one and the same.

The variables `foo1` and `foo2` have the same type and value as the `mySlice` variable. But the variable `foo3` has a different type, therefore also a different value. And yes, the **dynamic** type and value are the same as `mySlice` but the **static** type and value are not.

An interface value is NOT represented in memory by a structure that's compatible with the three-field `SliceHeader` and therefore it is wrong, not only semantically, to try to take the slice header off of an interface value. Instead, an interface value is represented by a 2-field structure (that's why in your attempt the third field is `0`). The first field points to the type information of the wrapped value, the second field points to the data of the wrapped value.

Something like this:

```golang
type iface struct {
    typ  uintptr
    data uintptr
}
```

And you can test this by doing this:

```golang
x := (*iface)(unsafe.Pointer(&foo3))
s := (*SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(x.data))
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", x)
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", s)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/2KUgCU8h7O7

---

Also, consider reading this: https://research.swtch.com/interfaces.