# Go recursion for struct fields - function vs. pointer method

Tags: arrays, go, recursion

Given an exemplary

```
type container struct {
  arr int[]
}
```

I want to *recursively* manipulate its `arr` array field values.

I have two options, functionally:

- a (*pointer receiver*) *method* on `container`, directly accessing its `arr` array
- a *function*, receiving the `arr` slice as parameter

*In any case, alternating start and end indices have to be passed as parameters to each recursive call.*

**Question:**
Are there any known, theoretically beneficial or detrimental impacts, mainly with regards to performance¹ and memory footprint, by using one implementation over the other and considering that `arr` will hold between `10^6` and `10^9` elements?

---

¹ running (unprofessionally bench-marked) test implementations, performance does not *seem* to be significantly different

Comment: _"unprofessionally bench-marked"_ Use go's testing tool which comes with built-in benchmarking capabilities.

Comment: @icza gotcha, yet I am interested in general pitfalls for these two implementations - e.g. '*(tail) recursion can not be optimized for pointer receiver methods*' or '*accessing struct fields is generally slower (or vice versa)*' or '*call stack size is going to be an issue with this implementation*'

Comment: The Go compiler performs lots of optimization and inlining which can vary from use case to use case, often giving surprising results (e.g. code being faster that logically should be slower). That's why I'm suggesting to benchmark _your_ code and see how they perform.

Comment: In general, using a pointer receiver method to manipulate the arr array directly may have better performance than passing the slice as a parameter to a function. This is because passing a large slice as a parameter to a function requires copying the slice header and underlying array, which can be costly in terms of memory and time, especially if the slice is very large (in your case, between 10^6 and 10^9 elements).

Comment: On the other hand, using a function with a slice parameter can have some advantages, such as making the code more modular and easier to test. It also avoids the potential issue of concurrent access to the same data structure, which can occur when using a method with a pointer receiver.
In terms of memory footprint, both approaches should be similar, as the underlying array of the slice will be shared between the struct and the function, and only the slice header and parameters need to be stored on the stack.

Comment: Overall, the choice between using a pointer receiver method or a function with a slice parameter may depend on the specific requirements and constraints of your use case, such as code modularity, concurrent access, and performance.

Comment: @techStud _"This is because passing a large slice as a parameter to a function requires copying the slice header and underlying array"_ - this is wrong. See [Are slices passed by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993688/are-slices-passed-by-value/39993797#39993797)

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can use both options, but I recommend to use pointer to array because it will protect you from accidental append to the slice which can lead to copying of the entire slice memory.

Also keep in mind that you cannot use array in such way:

```
func foo(sl []int) {
    sl[1] = 15
}

func main() {
    arr := [5]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    foo(arr)
}
```

Output:

```
cannot use arr (variable of type [5]int) as []int value in argument to foo
```

But you can convert array into slice without copying it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func foo(sl []int) {
    sl[1] = 55
}

func main() {
    arr := [5]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    sl := arr[:]

    fmt.Printf("arr=%v, sl=%v\n", arr, sl)

    arr[1] = 5
    fmt.Printf("arr=%v, sl=%v\n", arr, sl)

    sl[1] = 15
    fmt.Printf("arr=%v, sl=%v\n", arr, sl)

    foo(sl)
    fmt.Printf("arr=%v, sl=%v\n", arr, sl)
}
```

Output:

```
arr=[1 2 3 4 5], sl=[1 2 3 4 5]
arr=[1 5 3 4 5], sl=[1 5 3 4 5]
arr=[1 15 3 4 5], sl=[1 15 3 4 5]
arr=[1 55 3 4 5], sl=[1 55 3 4 5]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! And the warning, although I only ever need to switch elements, not change the size in any way. Looks like Go has no explicit tail recursion optimization whatsoever built in, and apparently won't have it for the time being. I went with the function way for now, not using a method on the struct - mainly because I was able to reuse it elsewhere.