# How do I pass a generic function as an argument to another function in golang?

Tags: function, go, generics, methods, higher-order-functions

How do i modify transformNumbers function so that it works with generic function doubleG and tripleG

```
type trandformFn func(int) int

func transformNumbers(numbers *[]int, transform trandformFn) []int {
    dNumbers := []int{}
    for _, value := range *numbers {
        dNumbers = append(dNumbers, transform(value))
    }
    return dNumbers
}

func double(value int) int {
    return 2 * value
}

func triple(value int) int {
    return 3 * value
}

func doubleG[T int | float64 | float32](value T) T {
    return 2 * value
}

func tripleG[T int | float64 | float32](value T) T {
    return 3 * value
}
```

I am confused with the transformFn type.

trying something like:

```
func transformNumbers(numbers *[]int, transform func[T int|float64|float32](T)T) []int {
    dNumbers := []int{}
    for _, value := range *numbers {
        dNumbers = append(dNumbers, transform(value))
    }
    return dNumbers
}
```

but getting error !!

```
func transformNumbers(numbers *[]int, transform func[T int|float64|float32](T)T) []int {
    dNumbers := []int{}
    for _, value := range *numbers {
        dNumbers = append(dNumbers, transform(value))
    }
    return dNumbers
}
```

expecting this to work but getting error!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use a generic function as a parameter of another function without instantiation, you also have to make that function generic. Also don't pass a pointer to a slice, that's unneeded (a slice value is already a header holding a pointer to a backing array). See [Are slices passed by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993688/are-slices-passed-by-value/39993797#39993797)

For example:

```
func transformNumbers[T int | float64 | float32](numbers []T, transform func(T) T) []T {
    dNumbers := []T{}
    for _, value := range numbers {
        dNumbers = append(dNumbers, transform(value))
    }
    return dNumbers
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println(transformNumbers([]int{1, 2, 3}, doubleG))
fmt.Println(transformNumbers([]float32{1, 2, 3}, doubleG))
fmt.Println(transformNumbers([]float64{1, 2, 3}, tripleG))
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/FN3uahm3vN3)):

```
[2 4 6]
[2 4 6]
[3 6 9]
```

You can of course create a `transformFn` type for the transformer functions, which also must be generic:

```
type transformFn[T int | float64 | float32] func(T) T

func transformNumbers[T int | float64 | float32](numbers []T, transform transformFn[T]) []T {
    dNumbers := []T{}
    for _, value := range numbers {
        dNumbers = append(dNumbers, transform(value))
    }
    return dNumbers
}
```

Usage is the same, try this one on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/wRaiKR5nICw).

You can also create a separate type for the constraint so you don't have to repeat the allowed types:

```
type allowedTypes interface {
    int | float64 | float32
}

type transformFn[T allowedTypes] func(T) T

func transformNumbers[T allowedTypes](numbers []T, transform transformFn[T]) []T {
    dNumbers := []T{}
    for _, value := range numbers {
        dNumbers = append(dNumbers, transform(value))
    }
    return dNumbers
}
```

Also note that preallocating the result slice and assinging each transformed value (without using `append()`) will be much faster, so do it like this:

```
func transformNumbers[T int | float64 | float32](numbers []T, transform func(T) T) []T {
    dNumbers := make([]T, len(numbers))
    for i, value := range numbers {
        dNumbers[i] = transform(value)
    }
    return dNumbers
}
```