# Golang var and literal usage

Tags: go, slice, var, literals

Option 1

```
var employees []Employee
session.Employees = employees
```

Option 2

```
session.Employees = []Employee{}
```

What, if any, is the difference in the two Golang code options, with respect to session.Employees after execution?

Answer (score 4):

Your first version assigns the value of the `employees` variable to `session.Employees`. It will be the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of the type `[]Employee`, which is `nil`. You could simply write this as:

```
session.Employees = nil
```

Your second version assigns the value of a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals), which will be an empty (length=0, capacity=0) but non-`nil` slice.

See related questions:

[nil slices vs non-nil slices vs empty slices in Go language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305170/nil-slices-vs-non-nil-slices-vs-empty-slices-in-go-language/44305910#44305910)

[What is the point of having nil slice and empty slice in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104157/what-is-the-point-of-having-nil-slice-and-empty-slice-in-golang/49106111#49106111)

[Correct way to initialize empty slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164375/correct-way-to-initialize-empty-slice/29164546#29164546)

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the links to elaborate on the subject.